# Extending word search selection in swiper

Tags: isearch, ivy, swiper

I have been using `helm` from some time and am now trying `ivy`, `counsel` and `swiper`.
Regarding `swiper` I am wondering if there is a way of **extending the word search selection**.

Just like hitting <kbd>C-w</kbd> after a normal incremental search command with <kbd>C-s</kbd>.
What it is called [Isearch Yank](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Isearch-Yank.html) in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `M-j`, which is bound to `ivy-yank-word` in the ivy minibuffer key map.

It's worth reading through the the ivy manual, either in Emacs or online. The relevant key bindings are discussed here: http://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-that-alter-the-minibuffer-input

Comment: Well, I read it, but bypassed that... Thanks!

Comment: @nephewtom FWIW, `C-h m` during `ivy` completion also pops up an `org-mode` reference document.